# sql select to extract and link the record above

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need some assistance with my extract. Below is a view of my data and how it is extract from a MS SQL database.

My challenge is that the database does not differentiate from the different "email address" . How do I link email address record to the record above.

```
Secid|Name|Question|Answer|
2|load1|Name of Principle|Joe Make|
2|load1|Contact Number|12234423|
2|load1|Email address|joemake@mymail.com|
2|load1|Name of Principle|Amy Soup|
2|load1|Contact Number of Principle|23134|
2|load1|Email address|amysoup@mymail.com|
2|load1|Name of Teacher|james blue|
2|load1|Contact Number|8787878|
2|load1|Email Address|jamesblue@mymail.com|
2|load1|Name of Secretary|CHARLES black|
2|load1|Contact Number|989897|
2|load1|Email Address|chblack@mymail.com|
```

Comment: Are those the only columns in the table?

Comment: there are columns, such as date but nothing to link the 2 records together. there is a column that i forgot to include, it is the schoolname column

Comment: So no identity column or anything that can identify the correct order? If not, there's really no way to guarantee an order and do this automatically...

Comment: the only guarantee is that when the data is saved from the web page to the database that it will be in that order.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any column to order by (e.g. a monotonically increasing identity column, or a timestamp), I'm afraid you're honestly out of luck. There is no way to guarantee any sort of ordering of the rows for any query.

What you *can* do, however, is export the data into an Excel sheet and then look at it manually and put the rows in the right order, assuming you can figure it out. Unfortunately this is really going to be the only way.

---

If you had a column you could order by, you can use a join to group the rows, assuming you had a way of identifying the start of each set - in your case a `Question like 'Name of %'` should probably work. Assuming an identity column called `Id`, something like:

```
select t.*, tGroupStart.Id as GroupId
from myTable t
join myTable tGroupStart on tGroupStart.Id <= t.Id
    and tGroupStart.Question like 'Name of %'
where not exists (
    select 1
    from myTable t2
    where t2.Id <= t.Id
    and t2.Question like 'Name of %'
    and t2.Id > tGroupStart.Id
)
```